How to hide the 1900 dates in my cells until dates are entered in a previous cell?
I am using this formula in conditional formatting for column E  =AND(E4<>"",E4-TODAY()=30).
I'm needing to hide the 1900 dates until the open date is entered, then the Columns E is +30 days, F is +60 days, and G is +90 days.
When I've tried other formulas to include BLANK, it takes away the conditional formatting.

Excel stores dates as numbers, and 0 => 1/0/1900. If all you want to do is hide the value, change the cell numberformat to mm/dd/yyyy;;;. That format says to show the date as mm/dd/yyyy if it is a positive value, but don't show anything if it is zero(0) or negative (or text, for that matter).

Formulas to incorporate into columns E, F and G:

In Cell E4 and fill down:
=IF([@[Home Open Date]]="","",[@[Home Open Date]]+30)


In Cell F4 and fill down:
=IF([@[Home Open Date]]="","",[@[Home Open Date]]+60)


In Cell G4 and fill down:
=IF([@[Home Open Date]]="","",[@[Home Open Date]]+90)



